# Updateing aws apigateway binaryMediaTypes

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I'm attempting to configure and update the binary support options of an AWS API Gateway. I can do this through the web UI without issue, but I would like to script this.

Using the CLI Command Reference pages:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/apigateway/get-rest-api.html
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/apigateway/update-rest-api.html

Able to issue a get-rest-api command just fine:

```
C:\> aws apigateway get-rest-api --rest-api-id [ID]

{
  "id": "[ID]",
    "createdDate": 1490723884,
    "name": "testbinarymediatypes"
}
```

But when attempting to update the binaryMediaTypes:

```
PS C:\> aws apigateway update-rest-api --rest-api-id [ID] --patch-operations op=add,path=binaryMediaTypes,value='image/jpg'
```

> An error occurred (BadRequestException) when calling the UpdateRestApi
>   operation: Invalid patch path binaryMediaTypes

Can this be done or am I stuck manually adding the types in the web UI every time?

Comment: We've also noticed that / needs to be encoded as ~1 when setting binaryMediaType using CloudFormation as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The format for adding these via the CLI is a little non-intuitive.

```
aws apigateway update-rest-api --rest-api-id [ID] 
          --patch-operations "op=add,path=/binaryMediaTypes/image~1jpg"
aws apigateway update-rest-api --rest-api-id [ID]
          --patch-operations "op=replace,path=/binaryMediaTypes/image~1jpg,value='image/gif'"
```

Comment: What is `image~1jpg?`?

Comment: Is the recommended way by AWS to add media types:
 Use ~1 instead of / in the media types, for example image~1png
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-apigateway-restapi.html

Answer (score 1):

I am placing this here for anyone looking for a similar solution to updating the apigateway endpointConfiguration.

```
aws apigateway update-rest-api --rest-api-id yourId --patch-operations "op=replace,path=/endpointConfiguration/types/EDGE,value='REGIONAL'"
```

Answer (score 0):

Another automation solution: deploy swagger.

For pulling I use this command:

```
aws apigateway get-export \
        --rest-api-id xxxxxxxxxx \
        --stage-name prod \
        --export-type swagger \
        --parameters '{"extensions": "integrations,authorizers"}' \
        --accepts application/yaml \
        swagger.yaml
```

At the end of `swagger.yaml` I see:

```
x-amazon-apigateway-binary-media-types:
- "image/png"
- "image/jpeg"
```

You can upload with this command:

```
aws apigateway put-rest-api \
        --rest-api-id '5y7lkvtie6' \
        --body 'file://swagger.yaml'
```

After you will need to deploy your stage through the web console or again with `awscli` (never tried yet, check `aws apigateway help` if it is possible).